# Scapy encapsulation example

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to define a new layer in scapy that contains an encapsulated IP packet.  Are there any examples or documentation for creating such a layer?  I imagine there would be a particular method to do this, such that the packet dissection is recursively applied to the encapsulated packet.

Currently I'm just creating the encapsulation header and sending like so:

```
send( IP( ... )/
      UDP( ... )/
      NEW_HEADER( ... )/
      IP( ... )/
      TCP( ... ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define your own layer according to the [scapy documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html) on adding new layers.

Here's a basic example, taken from the documentation:

```
class Disney(Packet):
    name = "DisneyPacket "
    fields_desc=[ ShortField("mickey",5),
                  XByteField("minnie",3) ,
                  IntEnumField("donald" , 1 ,
                              { 1: "happy", 2: "cool" , 3: "angry" } ) ]
```

Layers will automatically dissect and build based on the field descriptions.
I'd be best to also have a look at the existing layers in the `scapy.layers` package as there'll be most likely already a layer that is similar to the one you'd like to create as well as having a look at existing fields that you could reuse from `scapy.fields`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The question is a bit broad and the documentation fully explains it but anyway, I've added some more explanation.